# List and change directory and run command in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cygwin, sh

I am coming back to shell after almost 6 years or so.
I have a directory structure let's say,

> MainDirectory --> subDirectory1/some.xml
>                        --> subDirectory2/some.xml
>                        ...
>                        ...
>                        --> subDirectoryN/some.xml

And I want to execute some.xml in all the subdirectories and get the output to a file using ">" operator I guess.
What would be the proper script for this? I tried a couple of option and played around but couldn't achieve this. Can anybody please help?

Comment: What do you mean by 'executing' xml file ??

Comment: Let's say an ant job - build.xml

Comment: Look into the `find` command. For everything it finds you can -exec a command

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

You can do something like this :

```
cd <path_to_main_directory>
for subdir in */
do
    pushd "$subdir"
    <do_smth> some.xml > output.txt
    popd
done
```

Comment: why not `for subdir in */`? use of `ls` is almost always an issue with filenames having spaces.

Comment: I tested and looks like subdir in */ do not fix the issue of spaces in directory names ?

Comment: Oh nvm i see the difference now and think that it is a better solution. I edit

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you both. This will save me a lot of time. Could you have time to explain what are these?
in */
pushd 
popd

Comment: @Xavi you can do for file in \*; to loop on every file/folder, p\* will match every file/folder starting with p, \*/ will match only directories. pushd is like cd but keeps in memory your previous position. popd will get you back there.